# Is it possible to use "as" with the same meaning as "so"or "that"?

Tags: grammar

Is it possible to use "as" with the same meaning as "so","that" etc.

Examples:

You didn’t need to withdraw €500 from ATM. That smartphone doesn’t cost **as much**.

(...doesn’t cost so much/that much; ...doesn’t cost as much as you think.)

If we had reached Moscow without any problems, it wouldn’t have been **as interesting**.

(...as interesting as it actually was.)

Is it idiomatic?

Comment: For some reason, the second one sounds much more natural and idiomatic to me than the first. Leaving out the second part of ‘as X as Y’ requires that it be quite obvious what the second part is, and “as it was” in the second is somehow more obvious than “as you think” in the first.

Comment: 'As interesting' has an easily recoverable comparator, while 'as much' doesn't in your example ('as X does/did' is expected). You _can_ use 'You didn’t need to withdraw €500 from ATM. The smartphone doesn’t cost as much as that.'